# How can i plug an waterfall-chart like waterfall-chart in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

Is there a way to plot waterfall charts with oracle apex?

i found something way like i want "**below link**" but it didn't work with waterfall-chart
https://orclking.blogspot.com/2021/03/single-callback-to-draw-multiple-google.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the solution.
It is an example for using google chart in oracle apex.
you can write the below code in plsql region.

```
DECLARE
l_title VARCHAR2(240) := 'Example to Draw any Google Charts in Oracle APEX';
BEGIN 
  htp.p('<html>');
  htp.p('<head>');
  htp.p('<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>');
  htp.p('<script type="text/javascript">');

  -- Load Charts and the corechart and barchart packages.
  htp.p('google.charts.load(''current'', {''packages'':[''corechart'']})');
  htp.p('google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)');

  -- draw chart
  htp.p('function drawChart() { 
        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          [''Mon'', 0, 0, 38, 38],
          [''Tue'', 38, 38, 55, 55],
          [''Wed'', 55, 55, 77, 77],
          [''Thu'', 77, 77, 66, 66],
          [''Fri'', 0, 0, 66, 66]
          // Treat the first row as data.
        ], true);');

  htp.p('var waterfall_options = {title:''waterfall: '||l_title||''',
                                 width:500,
                                 height:300,
                                 pieHole: 0.4,
                                 legend: ''none'',
                                 bar: { groupWidth: ''80%'' }, // Remove space between bars.
                                 candlestick: {
                                    fallingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: ''red'' }, 
                                    risingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: ''blue'' } }  
                                    }' );
  htp.p('var waterfall = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart
         (document.getElementById(''CandlestickChartdiv''))');
  
  htp.p('waterfall.draw(data2, waterfall_options)');


  htp.p('}');
  htp.p('</script>');
  htp.p('</head>');
  htp.p('<body>');

  htp.p('<div id="CandlestickChartdiv" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div>');
 
  htp.p('</body>');
END;
```